# Sonic NDK file type is...??? Alternative to Sonic. Need to change Pitch of audio in android?

Tags: android, signal-processing, audio-recording, pitch

I downloaded Sonic NDK project from https://github.com/waywardgeek/sonic-ndk, as i know that it plays "talking.bin" by default which is in the projects raw folder, it's a binary file and i want to replace it with my own file in this project. So i created binary files of amr, wav and mp3 and tested in this project but nothing worked for me, as it is simply playing a noise instead of proper original audio. Any suggestions to play a file in sonic NDk project.

NOTE: My main aim is to change the pitch of an recorded audio file, which sonic is doing perfectly. Please suggest any better working alternative.

SOLUTION: I found the solution of this...

The SONIC ndk is playing pcm file.

You can convert any mp3 to pcm and then try that file to play is demo sonic project, you will be able to play the file.For the conversion of mp3 to pcm i used ffmpeg by using command

ffmpeg -y -i mymp3file.mp3 -f s16le -acodec pcm_s16le mypcmfile.pcm

Comment: SOLUTION: I found the solution of this...

The SONIC ndk is playing pcm file.

You can convert any mp3 to pcm and then try that file to play is demo sonic project, you will be able to play the file.For the conversion of mp3 to pcm i used ffmpeg by using command

ffmpeg -y -i mymp3file.mp3 -f s16le -acodec pcm_s16le mypcmfile.pcm